# Can i change template class type using template function parameter c++

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I want to change type of class from T to new_T, is it possible?

```
template<class T,int count>
class obj_pool{
  public:
    template<class new_T>
    void Retypedef();
};
```

For example obj_pool created for int`obj_pool<int> pool`, and when user calls`pool.Retypedef<double>()` function ,that pool becomes pool for double.

Comment: what type do you want to change? The question is rather unclear

Comment: `T` is just a name. You could use `new_T`, `chicken` or `StackOverflow` instead, and it'd give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

No.

In the future, when you write a question, include some information about the underlying problem you are trying to solve.  Then when your atttempted solution is a dead end, people answering can solve the underlying problem for you.

Or ask a new question (via ask a question button) about that underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `T` and `new_T` are two different parameters. Using this template could look like this:

```
obj_pool<int,3> x;
x.Retypedef<double>();   // <- passing different types for new_T
x.Retypedef<float>();    // <- does not change the type of x

x.Retypedef<int>();      // ..and of course you can use the same type for
                         // new_T as for T
```

If you want `new_T` to be always the same as `T` then you could simply write:

```
template<class T,int count>
class obj_pool{
  public:
    void Retypedef();   // can use T 
};
```